# Changing a program to be used on a webserver

Tags: python, mobile, webserver

Say I have code written in python that analyzes files on my computer and returns a result. It works great locally on my HD, but now I'd like to turn it into a mobile app. This means I'll require a server of some kind (cloud for instance) where users can access it.

It is my understanding that all that would be required is a method to grant user credentials and permissions to the patrons so they can access the "run" command in my analysis program. But honestly, I have no ZERO visibility in this area and don't really know where to begin.

I only have two questions:

1. Users & their credentials are endless, but they all have to share the same analysis program. I don't know much about servers, but wouldn't this method cause long queue times? Generally-speaking what considerations would I have to make in my analysis code to avoid this?
2. Can someone just point me in the direction of what I'd need to learn in order to answer the above question? This topic is a bottomless pit of information and I don't wanna get trapped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is an MVC Web framework which possesses all features required for doing Web applications with Python. Simply go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) and you should be up and running in no time, *on your local machine*.

To deploy there are various options, be it a cloud instance (a lot of providers here, including Rackspace and Amazon, Google for "django web hosting"), or "traditional" server machines (again a lot of providers here).

The "mobile" part is just the user interface. This affects decisions in the presentation part of your application, and you can restricted this to the *View* part in Django jargon (i.e. the HTML templates) of your Web application. You can look for frameworks which allow the production of aesthetically decent (or better) user interfaces HTML tailored for mobile/tablet devices, e.g. [JQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Therefore direction: start with Django -> deploy on a server "somewhere" -> tailor your user interface for mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i have a road sign. Immeasurably helpful.